# How save custom meta type posts multicheck grouped by taxonomy (with CMB2)

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, metabox

I'm using CMB2 (https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2) for add new meta to post types.

I'm trying to add a new custom meta with a list of posts grouped by taxonomy, but I do not know how to save them.
I would like to save the meta as an array as follows:

```
array (
  id => array (checked, new_title),
  id2 => array (checked, new_title2)
)
```

[image: custom meta]

The source code for custom meta:

```
// Enqueue accordion scripts.
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function($hook){
    if (( 'post.php' == $hook ) || ( 'post-new.php' == $hook)) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'accordion', '/wp-admin/js/accordion.js');
    }
});

// Custom CMB2 field list_category_posts
add_action( 'cmb2_render_post_multicheck_by_category', 'cmb2_render_post_multicheck_by_category', 10, 5 );
function cmb2_render_post_multicheck_by_category ( $field, $value, $object_id, $object_type, $field_type  ) {

    // get post_type
    if ($field->args[query_args][post_type])
        if (post_type_exists($field->args[query_args][post_type]))
            $type=$field->args[query_args][post_type];
        else $type=get_post_type($object_id);
    else $type=get_post_type($object_id);

    // get taxonomy    
    if ($field->args[query_args][taxonomy])
        if (taxonomy_exists($field->args[query_args][taxonomy]) && is_object_in_taxonomy($type, $field->args[query_args][taxonomy]))
            $taxonomy=$field->args[query_args][taxonomy];
        else $taxonomy=get_object_taxonomies($type)[0];
    else $taxonomy=get_object_taxonomies($type)[0];

    $posts_data = array();
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $posts = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => $type,
            'tax_query' => array(array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'terms' => $term->term_id
            ))
        ));
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $posts_data[$term->name][$post->ID] = array ($post->post_title);
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="accordion-container">
        <ul class="outer-border">
        <?php foreach ($posts_data as $category => $posts) { ?>
            <li class="control-section accordion-section">
                <h3 class="accordion-section-title hndle" tabindex="0">
                    <?php echo $category; ?>
                </h3>
                <?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
                    <div class="accordion-section-content" style="display: none;">
                        <label class="menu-item-title ">
                            <div><input type="checkbox" class="menu-item-checkbox" value="<?php echo $field_type->_id=$post->ID; ?>">
                            <span><?php echo $post[0]; ?></span>
                                <input type="text">
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Usage:

```
add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', function () {
    $prefix = 'recipes_';

    $cmb_recipes = new_cmb2_box( array(
        'id'            => $prefix . 'metabox',
        'title'         => 'Posts multicheck by category',
        'object_types'  => array( 'recipes', ), // post type
    ) );

    $cmb_recipes->add_field( array(
        'name'       => '',
        'id'         => $prefix . 'ingredients',
        'type'       => 'post_multicheck_by_category',
        'context' => 'side',
        'query_args' => array (
            'post_type' => 'ingredients',
            'taxonomy' => 'ingredients-category',
        ),
    ) );

} );
```

Comment: I would note that the above code will run into scaling issues, for example, if i have 1000 terms and assign them to 50 posts each, that's 1 large term query + 1000 post queries, 50,000 posts fetched from the database, and a multidimensional nested array of 50k post titles. Most servers will run out of time before the page has finished generating. I recommend using an autocomplete system with a REST API endpoint/AJAX

Comment: Note that this is why the tag list doesn't list every tag to choose from, and auto-completes, and it's also a major differences between ACF v4 and v5. You should also pay attention to escaping. Right now I could specify that I want to check a term named `<script>alert('hacked you')'</script>`

Comment: You're right, I need to validate with esc_attr, I'm still developing it, but my problem is regarding saving the data in the database.

Comment: I know it could be a problem with a database with thousands of records, but for a simple project structuring well the categories might be valid.
Surely in the long run you would have to add the option to search through the REST API with AJAX.

Comment: downvoted and closevoted as you have a generic issue, but you are forcing yourself into a specific corner by insisting on using a specific library. With that library you are limited to whatever it offers, and therefor it is better to ask its authors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you would in any other HTML form

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="email[]" />

<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="email[]" />

<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="email[]" />
```

The above will give you arrays instead of singular values in PHP, so $_POST['name'] is an array of 3 values.

The same is true of your checkboxes, give them all the same name with a `[]` on the end. Use post IDs as their values, and you have your data structure, a simple array of post IDs